# Configure JMeter as TCP server to receive messages?

Tags: java, tcp, jmeter

I have ReST service, which calls a method to send the generated information to another endpoint using TCP, is there any way that with Jmeter that when I send a ReST request and should be able to host TCP server in my JMeter to receive the response sent when service called?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have a TCP server in JMeter you can get one using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the following minimal code snippet:

```
def socketServer = new ServerSocket(1234)

while (true) {
    socketServer.accept { socket ->
        socket.withStreams { input, output ->
            log.info("Received message: ${input.newReader().readLine()}")
        }
    }
}
```

it will start the TCP server on the port 1234, listen to incoming connections and printing the received data to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

If you're receiving HTTP, not TCP you might rather want to go for [HTTP Mirror Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Mirror_Server) which is listening to incoming HTTP connections and returns the received data

Comment: First of all thank you, it is working fine as per my requirement. Now I facing another issue while running jmeter script with your recommended code, the jmeter is unable to shutdowm it's stuck into infinite loop.